# I have to make an LED with an ultrasonic distance sensor, where the LED blinks faster when getting closer than a specific distance

Tags: arduino-uno

I already have this code, but I do not know how to make the LED blink.

CODE:

```cpp
const int ledPin = 6; // The pin of your LED, D06
const int trigPin = 5; // The pin to which the TRIG is connected, D05
const int echoPin = 4; // The pin to which the ECHO is connected, D04
const int ledOnTime = 1000;
// The time that the LED stays on, after detecting the motion (in milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s)
const int trigDistance = 40;
// The distance (and lower than it) at which the sensor is triggered (in centimeters)
//
int duration;
int distance;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  if (distance <= trigDistance) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(ledOnTime);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: I corrected the formatting and also added indention. You should really use indention. It makes the code way more readable. The Arduino IDE even has an autoformatting function to introduce correct indention

Answer (score 1):

I would say the way to go is using non-blocking code with `millis()`. Look into the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE. It doesn't use `delay()`, which is considered bad coding practice, since it is just busy waiting. Nothing else can happen during a delay, except for interrupts. Instead of waiting it is better to regularily check the clock, if it is time to do something (much like you would do in real life for example for baking a pizza).

The clock is provided by `millis()`, which returns the number of milliseconds since startup. Below you see the `BlinkWithoutDelay`example. The variable `interval` controls the blink frequency. If you remove the `const` keyword before it and change it according to the measurements from the ultrasonic sensor, you will get a changing blinking frequency with changing distance.

Try to combine the codes into one. Remove all `delay()` calls, except for the `delay(1)` (it is needed to trigger the ultrasonic sensor and it is small enough to not matter greatly).

```
const int ledPin =  LED_BUILTIN;// the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED

// Generally, you should use "unsigned long" for variables that hold time
// The value will quickly become too large for an int to store
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// constants won't change:
const long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.

  // check to see if it's time to blink the LED; that is, if the difference
  // between the current time and last time you blinked the LED is bigger than
  // the interval at which you want to blink the LED.
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

The rest is up to you. If you need more information about the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, you should google it. There are tons of tutorials. This is a great coding excerise, so have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

**step 1**: define your MIN_DISTANCE, MAX_DISTANCE

**step 2**: get distance from sensor

**step 3**: rescale the distance value to a value in between 0 and 255

**step 4**: fade led according to the rescaled value.

Note that: you should not use delay() to blink LED. Use analogWrite() instead. See  [the example](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-potentiometer-fade-led). We can change frequency of PWM to make LED from fading to blinking by using setPwmFrequency() function